# VSCode Python write to Debug Console

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am brand new to **VSCode** with Python.  Is it possible to write to the tab **DEBUG CONSOLE** (only) from Python code?  I have Googled but found nothing on this.

The debugger does this internally, e.g. on a breakpoint set to **Log Message**.  For the moment, if I use `print()` that does go to **DEBUG CONSOLE**, but it also goes to **TERMINAL** tab, which I'd rather it did not.  The `launch.json` has `"console": "integratedTerminal"` if that is relevant.

Comment: If you are interested in using this setting globally (it is per-debug-configuration currently), you may want to upvote this feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18353

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set [`"console": "internalConsole"` to have output go to the debug console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, this causes output *only* to **DEBUG CONSOLE**!  It wasn't quite what I wanted --- I wanted a call from Python code which achieved that regardless of `"console"` setting, I might want `integratedTerminal` for elsewhere in code.  I don't understand from the docs why `"integratedTerminal"` causes output to *both* **DEBUG CONSOLE** *and* **TERMINAL** tabs, but there you are.  Unless you respond further, I will mark yours as the Accepted Solution soon, thanks!

Comment: @JonBrave what you're after isn't currently supported. You can file a feature request at github.com/microsoft/ptvsd if you would like that feature.

Comment: Ah, that would explain why it currently doesn't work that way!  Thanks.  I'll mark this as the effective solution.

Comment: That option does or might have this issue re input https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73993577/in-vs-code-when-running-a-python-program-via-the-debugger-with-internalconsole